# Check key exists in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdictionary

how can I check if this exists?:

```
[[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPathSet.row] valueForKey:@"SetEntries"]
```

I want to know whether this key exists or not. How can I do that?

Thank you very much :)

**EDIT:
dataArray has Objects in it. And these objects are NSDictionaries.**

Comment: Any reason why you’re using `-valueForKey:` instead of `-objectForKey:`? The former is used in key-value coding and is slightly slower than the latter.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

I presume that `[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPathSet.row]` is returning an [`NSDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary), in which case you can simply check the result of `valueForKey` against `nil.`

For example:

```
if ([[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPathSet.row] valueForKey:@"SetEntries"] != nil) {
    // The key existed...

}
else {
    // No joy...

}
```

Comment: the value of that key can also be nil therefore this approach will not fully test if a key exists or not in the dictionary

Comment: @AndreiA.You can't add nil to an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 47):

So I know you already selected an answer, but I found this to be rather useful as a category on `NSDictionary`. You start getting into efficiency at this point with all these different answers. Meh...6 of 1...

```
- (BOOL)containsKey: (NSString *)key {
     BOOL retVal = 0;
     NSArray *allKeys = [self allKeys];
     retVal = [allKeys containsObject:key];
     return retVal;
}
```

Comment: I also wrote the same method in my category, but I have a weird crash happened when I use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(). after narrow down, I change the method name from containsKey => hasKey and the crash disappeared

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer. I want to search by a key and not if the value of the key is nil or not. You could have a key in a dictionary that points to a nil value. Yet the key exists. The accepted answer doesn't cover this scenario. But this solution here does.

Comment: @Hooman: Not true about a key having a value of nil: the second paragraph of the NSDictionary documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states that "Neither a key nor a value can be nil; if you need to represent a null value in a dictionary, you should use NSNull." Both this and the accepted answer work for your scenario, i.e. with a dictionary where a value for some key is null (of type NSNull).

Comment: Or: return [[self allKeys] containsObject:key] ? YES : NO;

Comment: good callout, @Jamo.  I'd steer way clear of this answer. my guess is that under the covers, both the call to allKeys and the call to containsObject are each at least O(n), while valueForKey is likely much less.

Answer (score 34):

Check if it's nil:

```
if ([[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPathSet.row] valueForKey:@"SetEntries"] != nil) {
    // SetEntries exists in this dict
} else {
    // No SetEntries in this dict
}
```

Comment: the value of that key can also be nil therefore this approach will not fully test if a key exists or not in the dictionary

Comment: @AndreiA. Neither a key nor a value can be `nil` in an NSDictionary. To represent nil, you can use NSNull.

Answer (score 9):

this also works using Objective-C literals using the following syntax:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"key1" : @"value1", @"key2" : @"value2" };
if (dict[@"key2"])
NSLog(@"Exists");
else
NSLog(@"Does not exist");
```

Comment: For swift version below code works.                                                         let headers:Dictionary = httpResponse .allHeaderFields
                    
                    if (headers["errorcode"] != nil)
                    {
                        print("error key exists ")
                        
                    }

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ([dict objectForKey:@"bla"]) {
   // use obj
} else {
   // Do something else like create the object
}
```

Comment: This may be a technically correct explanation, but you'll be serving the community better (and likely getting more upvotes) if you provide more detailed discussion about your reasoning in the body of your answer. Why is it appropriate to use `objectForKey:` instead of another method? Why don't you explicitly have to check for a value? At the very least, using the code example provided in the question would make it easier to tie your example to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This one does the same but with less code:

```
if (dataArray[indexPathSet.row][@"SetEntries"] != nil) { /* the key exists */        } 
else                                                   { /* the key doesn't exist */ }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if ((NSNull *)[[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPathSet.row] valueForKey:@"SetEntries"] != nil) {
    // SetEntries exists in this dict
} else {
    // No SetEntries in this dict
}
```

That's the right answer.

Comment: what's the cast from BOOL to NSNull* for?

Answer (score -1):

Check dictionary contains any value. I prefer  [dic allKeys].count > 0 to check.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score -1):

Use the `(unsigned long)` option:

```
if ( (unsigned long)[[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPathSet.row] valueForKey:@"SetEntries"] ) {
    // Key exist;
}else{
    // Key not exist;
};
```

Comment: Casting the pointer to an object to `unsigned long` serves no purpose.