# NSUserDefaults: How to get value

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am new in iOS, Object-C and I am trying to do a simple login/registerLogin using NSUserDefaults.

My problem is: How could I access/get the value saved in NSUserDefaults to verify if an user already exist?

This is the code for registering a new user:

```
-(void)registerNewUser {

// Getting username and the password
NSString *newUsername = self.usernameRegisterTextField.text;
NSString *newPassword = self.passwordRegisterTextField.text;

// Using NSUserDefaults to storage username and password
NSUserDefaults *newUser = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[newUser setObject:newUsername forKey:@"username"];
[newUser setObject:newPassword forKey:@"password"];
[newUser setBool:YES forKey:@"registered"];

[newUser synchronize];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"registerSucessSegue" sender:nil];
```

}

And I am trying to get the value saved in NSUserDefaults to verify if an user already exist instead of calling the login screen again:

```
- (IBAction)productTableButton:(id)sender {
// Verification if an user exist
NSUserDefaults *newUser = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

BOOL newUserExist = [newUser valueForKey:@"registered"];

if (newUserExist == YES) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"productSegue" sender:nil];
} else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:nil];
}
```

}

Is there something that I am doing wrong when I am trying to access the value of an user saved in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Never use `valueForKey` to get a `BOOL`, btw never use `valueForKey` anyway with `NSUserDefaults`. There is `boolForKey`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `valueForKey` returns objects, not primitive data types like `BOOL`.
For `NSUserDefaults`, the shortest way to get a `BOOL` value is to use `boolForKey` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check [`objectForKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1410095-objectforkey?preferredLanguage=occ), which is safe to use for any type that could be associated with your key.

If the key has been previously set, it will return an `id`; otherwise, it will return nil. If it is a boolean, you will get an NSNumber which can easily be converted.

```
id someKey = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key"];
if(someKey)
{
    //User exists
}
else
{
    //User doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: "objectForKey, which is safe to use for any type that could be associated with your key." Sorry, that's incorrect. objectForKey only works for objects, not primitive data types like BOOL.

Comment: Idk why people downvoted this answer. This answer answers OP's question. He wanted to know how to check if a user exist and that can be done by checking if that key exist in userdefaults which is what this answer does.

Comment: @moonman239 primitive data like BOOL and int, etc. are all stored as NSNumbers, since NSDictionaries cannot handle primitives. ObjectForKey does indeed work in this case; the only difference is that boolForKey automatically performs the conversion from NSNumber to BOOL for you. This is the accepted way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635106/check-key-exists-in-nsdictionary

Comment: @David: Sorry, I cannot undo my downvote at this point. In any case, your answer at first read seemed to be suggesting that objectForKey returns BOOL types and not NSNumber objects.

Answer (score -1):

Try to get the value by using **boolForKey**:

`BOOL newUserExist = [defaults boolForKey:@"registered"];`